Solution of a variational problem.
If $ y $ is a stationary function of
$$
I(y) = \int_{-1}^1 (1 - x^2)(y')^2 \, dx, \quad y(-1) = 1 = y(1)
$$
subject to the constraint
$$
\int_{-1}^1 y^2 \, dx = 1,
$$
find $ y $, if it exists.
I approached this as an isoperimetric problem. Let us assume the Lagrangian is
$$
h = (1 - x^2)(y')^2 + \lambda y^2,
$$
which must satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\partial h}{\partial y'} \right) = 0.
$$
After solving the Euler-Lagrange equation, we obtain the following differential equation:
$$
((1 - x^2) y')' + \lambda y = 0, \quad y(-1) = 1 = y(1).
$$
This is a Sturm-Liouville problem. I observe that if we substitute $ x = \pm 1 $ into the above equation, we get $ \lambda = 0 $. Therefore, we are left with
$$
((1 - x^2) y')' = 0, \quad y(-1) = 1 = y(1).
$$
However, the solution appears to be undefined at $ x = \pm 1 $. How should I proceed to solve this further?
Thank you.

Should your $y^2$ term actually be $y$?

@JoshB. Edited ..........

This is a famous differential equation called the Legendre Differential Equation. It has known solutions if and only if $\lambda=n(n+1)$. See wikipedia for the equation and resulting solutions, and notice that it is not possible to satisfy both the constraint and the boundary conditions simultaneously due to the nature of the polynomial solutions.

@JoshB. What I did is not correct?

@JoshB. I like to approach without knowledge of Legendre Differential Equation.

Even if you dont start of with that knowledge, it's what you will eventually end up at.

You can substitute $x=\pm 1$ only after you take the derivative.

The Lagrangian penalty term should be $\lambda (y^2 - 1/2)$

A physicist's approach.
Since the differential equation is difficult to solve, let's try an approximate solution.
We are looking for the extremal of the functional in the form
$$y(x)=1+c_{1}(1-x^2)+c_{2}(1-x^2)(1+x)$$
Placing this expression into the functional and the constraint, we get
$$I(c_{1},c_{2})=\frac{16}{105}(7c_{1}^2+14c_{1}c_{2}+12c_{1}^2)$$
$$\frac{16}{15}c_{1}^2+c_{1}\left (\frac{8}{3}+ \frac{35}{15}c_{2} \right )+ \frac{128}{105}c_{2}^2+ \frac{8}{3}c_{2}+2=1$$
So we're looking extrema for function of two variables $I(c_{1},c_{2})$ under given constraint.
I will skip these calculations and give only the results
It turns out that there are four solutions:

$c_{1}=-\frac{25+3\sqrt{105}}{16}$ and $c_{2}=\frac{3\sqrt{105}}{16}$

$c_{1}=\frac{3\sqrt{105}-25}{16}$ and $c_{2}=-\frac{3\sqrt{105}}{16}$

$c_{1}=-\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}{4}$ and $c_{2}=0$

$c_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{10}-5}{4}$ and $c_{2}=0$


And so we have four extremals.
Inserting these into the functional we have respectively:

$I=\frac{65}{12}=5.41...$

$I=\frac{65}{12}=5.41...$

$I=\frac{7+2\sqrt{10}}{3}=4.44...$

$I=\frac{7-2\sqrt{10}}{3}=0.22...$


If greater accuracy is required, an extremal can be taken in the form of
$$y(x)=1+c_{1}(1-x^2)+c_{2}(1-x^2)(1+x)+c_{3}(1-x^2)(1+x)^2$$
